# Is it possible for two very similar but different set of data samples to produce the exact same encoding in an autoencoder

Tags: autoencoder, encoder

Suppose we have two identical images, but one image is a little brighter than the other. Is it possible that an undercomplete autoencoder will produce the exact same set of encoding values for these two images.If this is true what is the mathematical proof this?

Also if that is the case, can we build an encoder that sensitive to this and produces a different encoding or the slightest change in the inputs. What I see instead is an autoencoder that is 'robust' to little perturbations in the inputs. I would like a mathematical explanation for this please.